# Cannot draw DeviceContext contents

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express, slimdx

I have attempted to convert the SimpleTriangle sample to VB with mixed success. While I can create a Window to draw to and clear it to a background colour, I cannot seem to actually draw my triangle. I cannot for the life of me tell where the code is falling over. When I run it, I get the window (with a red background as expected) but now triangle. Can any one shed some light? Code is below - the TEMP.RunMe method is called from Sub Main.

```
Imports SlimDX.Direct3D11
Imports SlimDX
Imports SlimDX.D3DCompiler
Imports SlimDX.DXGI
Imports SlimDX.Windows
Imports Device = SlimDX.Direct3D11.Device
Imports Resource = SlimDX.Direct3D11.Resource

Namespace Test
Class TEMP
    Public form = New RenderForm("MyTest")
    Public device As Device
    Public swapChain As SwapChain
    Public viewport As New Viewport
    Public renderTarget As RenderTargetView
    Public context As DeviceContext

    Public Sub New()
        Dim Vertices As DataStream
        Dim vertexBuffer As Buffer
        Dim vertexShader As VertexShader
        Dim pixelShader As PixelShader
        Dim inputSignature As ShaderSignature
        Dim description As New SwapChainDescription()
        Dim elements() As InputElement
        Dim layout As InputLayout

        With description
            .BufferCount = 1
            .Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            .OutputHandle = form.handle
            .IsWindowed = True
            .ModeDescription = New ModeDescription(0, 0, New Rational(60, 1), DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm)
            .SampleDescription = New SampleDescription(1, 0)
            .Flags = DXGI.SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch
            .SwapEffect = DXGI.SwapEffect.Discard
        End With

        Direct3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.None, description, device, swapChain)
        viewport = New Viewport(0.0F, 0.0F, form.clientsize.width, form.clientsize.height)

        context = device.ImmediateContext
        context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(renderTarget)
        context.Rasterizer.SetViewports(viewport)

        Using resource As Resource = Direct3D11.Resource.FromSwapChain(Of Texture2D)(swapChain, 0)
            renderTarget = New RenderTargetView(device, resource)
        End Using

        Using bytecode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("triangle.fx", "VShader", "vs_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None)
            inputSignature = ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(bytecode)
            vertexShader = New VertexShader(device, bytecode)
        End Using

        Using bytecode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("triangle.fx", "PShader", "ps_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None)
            pixelShader = New PixelShader(device, bytecode)
        End Using

        Vertices = New DataStream(12 * 3, True, True)
        With Vertices
            .Write(New Vector3(0.0F, 0.5F, 0.5F))
            .Write(New Vector3(0.5F, -0.5F, 0.5F))
            .Write(New Vector3(-0.5F, -0.5F, 0.5F))
            .Position = 0
        End With

        elements = {New InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32_Float, 0)}
        layout = New InputLayout(device, inputSignature, elements)
        vertexBuffer = New Buffer(device, Vertices, 12 * 3, ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0)

        With context
            .InputAssembler.InputLayout = layout
            .InputAssembler.PrimitiveTopology = PrimitiveTopology.TriangleList
            .InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, New VertexBufferBinding(vertexBuffer, 12, 0))
            .VertexShader.Set(vertexShader)
            .PixelShader.Set(pixelShader)
        End With

        vertexBuffer.Dispose()
        layout.Dispose()
        vertexShader.Dispose()
        pixelShader.Dispose()
        inputSignature.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub mainLp()
        With context
            .ClearRenderTargetView(renderTarget, New Color4(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F))
            .Draw(3, 0)
        End With

        swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None)
    End Sub

    Public Sub RunMe()
        MessagePump.Run(form, New MainLoop(AddressOf mainLp))
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub Dispose()
        renderTarget.Dispose()
        swapChain.Dispose()
        device.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class
End Namespace
```

Traingle.fx contents are:

```
float4 VShader(float4 position : POSITION) : SV_POSITION
   {
return position;
   }

float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION) : SV_Target
   {
return float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found my problem. I try to use the renderTarget variable in the statement context.OutputMerger.SetTargets(renderTarget) before renderTarget has been initialized. Moving the statement after renderTarget=New RenderTargetView(device,resource) solves the problem.

Don't know how I missed that!